# Tensor product of $L^2$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

For Tensor-products on $L^2$ spaces I am Aware of the following property:

I know that $L^2(X,\mathbb{R})\otimes L^2(X,\mathbb{R}) \simeq L^2(X^2,\mathbb{R}).$

I was wondering if this is also true for Hilbert-space valued function functions, i.e.
$L^2(X,H) \otimes L^2(X,H) \simeq L^2(X^2,H)$?

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

The problem seems to be that $L^2(X,H) \simeq L^2(X,\mathbb{C}) \otimes H.$ Thus,
$L^2(X^2,H) \simeq L^2(X^2,\mathbb{C}) \otimes H.$

The left-hand side however is $L^2(X,\mathbb{C}) \otimes H\otimes L^2(X,\mathbb{C}) \otimes H.$

Comment: You should write out the homomorphism in the first case and see if anything breaks in the latter case.

Comment: @CameronWilliams yes, something breaks that is precisely why I am asking.

Comment: You can rearrange your tensor products. On the left you'll get a tensor product of $L^2$ spaces (which you know what to do with) and on the right, you'll have a tensor product of Hilbert spaces which you can't really simplify any further.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Tensor products are not commutative, so what does rearranging mean?

Comment: Right, but you can make an isomorphism in this case since one is just a function space.

Comment: @Cameron Williams sorry, your comments are a bit hard to understand for me. I simplified the expression in my question as far as possible. Why don't you turn your comments into an answer, please?

Comment: @CameronWilliams so you claim that the statement is true, because at the moment I think it is false.

Comment: Not quite! I think it should be $H\otimes H$ :) not just $H$ on the right hand side of your proposed equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to note is that in this case, tensor products are commutative. This is because one of our Hilbert spaces is a function space and assumes scalar values. The usual isomorphism $L^2(X,H)$ to $L^2(X,\Bbb C) \otimes H$ actually works just fine for $H\otimes L^2(X,\Bbb C) $ - this just amounts to moving our scalar to the right rather than left.

Thus you can write your last expression as $L^2(X,\Bbb C) \otimes L^2(X,\Bbb C) \otimes H\otimes H$. The first two combine to give $L^2(X^2,\Bbb C) $, giving $L^2(X^2,\Bbb C) \otimes (H\otimes H) $ which we realize as

$$L^2(X^2,H\otimes H). $$

This does not seem to properly simplify in the case of $H=\Bbb R$ (or $\Bbb C$), but it does. The reason is that $\Bbb R$ is one dimensional over itself (same with $\Bbb C$) so the tensor product with itself is going to be one dimensional, so it will just be $\Bbb R$ again (or $\Bbb C$). Thus the above expression simplifies to what you had in your first expression.